# Do I have to re-apply for work permit if I have stamp-4?

Tags: ireland, working-visas

I worked in Ireland for 6 years and I had stamp-4. However, I left Ireland last March and my stamp-4 expired in between.

Now I gave a job offer from Ireland and I want to avail that opportunity. Do I have to reapply for a work permit?

Or there is a simpler process as I already stamp-4 but that expired.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Usual answer is yes, you should reapply.

But right now Ireland extended all immigration permission from 20 September 2020 to 20 January 2021. If your expiration date falls in this period, you still have a valid stamp 4.

https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/immigration_and_employment_permits_during_covid19.html